# Intellij idea build .war manually

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, war

I am new to java web services. I have a java project in intellij with web service framework enabled. I am using `jetty server`.

To deploy the project locally I created a artifact and defined a configuration to deploy on `jetty`. Everything is working fine.

Now I deployed my project to `google cloud`. For the first time I copied the war manually. But now I want to build the war on the `google cloud instance` itself. How to build a war from code? There are many tutorials to build a war but I want to build it in the style intellij does it. So that there will always be consistency between the production server and my local server.

I also tried to see the intellij logs in case the steps are getting printed while building a war in intellij. But no help from this. Following logs are getting printed:

```
2015-08-26 14:03:05,395 [5647274]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 12590 ms 
2015-08-26 14:03:14,008 [5655887]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-08-26 14:03:15,525 [5657404]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-08-26 14:03:22,215 [5664094]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update canceled 
2015-08-26 14:03:23,023 [5664902]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 99 ms 
2015-08-26 14:03:33,446 [5675325]   INFO - .GenericCompilerPersistentData - Compiler info file doesn't exists: /Users/aapa/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/compiler/supertext.144ac7bb/.caches/jasper_validator/info 
2015-08-26 14:03:33,447 [5675326]   INFO - ler.impl.GenericCompilerRunner - Clearing cache for Jasper Validator 
2015-08-26 14:03:33,471 [5675350]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 3 took 19472 ms: 0 min 19sec 
2015-08-26 14:03:34,758 [5676637]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-08-26 14:03:36,370 [5678249]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 4589 ms 
2015-08-26 14:03:38,552 [5680431]   INFO - ins.idea.svn.SvnChangeProvider - Rename not found for /Users/aapa/Projects/trunk/core/conf/spr.properties 
2015-08-26 14:03:48,657 [5690536]   INFO - ins.idea.svn.SvnChangeProvider - Rename not found for /Users/aapa/Projects/trunk/core/conf/spr.properties
```

Pls tell me how to write my own build script? How to approach it? My java web services concepts are not so strong.

Following is my directory structure:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── libs
│   ├── common
│   ├── es
│   ├── logger
│   ├── rest
│   ├── spring
│   ├── test
│   ├── validation
│   └── ws
├── logs
├── resources
│   ├── conf
├── src
│   └── com
├── supertext.iml
├── test
│   └── com
└── web
    ├── WEB-INF
    ├── login.jsp
    ├── resources
    └── ui
```

Answer (score 0):

To my point of view i suggest that if you are new use maven for the build, it has a lot of task to use to build the war ready to deploy for jetty/tomcat (the structure are now the same), and it's the most used technology right now for the build.
Me i'm using gradle, i'm new to this, but my colleague are using it, and i have to use it, it is good but i think it has a little bit of problem for the team working, and it is in groovy, some says is good to write a build like they are coding, to me it's not so good and not so easy because i'm coming from a long ant experience and gradle it's completely different.